# CSV mapper class does map from list

Tags: c#, .net, csv

(updated version)
I'm reading dates from csv using csv mapper (CsvClassMap)

```
 void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
   using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{       
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<LoanRecord >();
    var records = csv.GetRecords<LoanRecord >();
}
}

public class LoanRecord : Model
{
    public LoanRecord()
    {
    }
    public string[] LoanStart_DateTime = new string[2];
    public string[] LoanEnd_DateTime = new string[2];


}
```

Mapper class:

```
 public sealed class LoanMapper: CsvClassMap<LoanRecord>
  {
    public LoanMapper()
    {
        Map(m => m.LoanStart_DateTime[0]).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.LoanEnd_DateTime[0]).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.LoanStart_DateTime[1]).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.LoanEnd_DateTime[1]).Index(3);
    }}


  csv format:
  LoanStart_DateTime1,LoanEnd_DateTime1,LoanStart_DateTime2,LoanEnd_DateTime2
  01/12/2022 00:00,02/12/2022 00:00,23/05/2022 00:00,23/05/2022 03:00,
```

somehow my mapper class doesn't recognize the list 'Not a member access Parameter name: expression', any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That error is caused by the attempt to map to a string (`m.LoanStart_DateTime[0]`). 
Essentially the line of code `Map(m => m.LoanStart_DateTime[0]).Index(0);` can be split into two halves. The Map-To and the Map-From.
`Map(m => m.LoanStart_DateTime[0])` is your Map-To which is impossible as you can't map to a string directly - you map to the member and the mapper tries to populate the member type value.
`.Index(0)` is your Map-From - you're saying "Map the value from the Header at location 0" into the Map-To property value for the member called "`LoanStart_DateTime[0]`" which doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CSVHelper package, you can manually iterate over the csv as it's being read. It then just requires some indexing logic to create a class for each pair of columns (obviously changing the index increment if you need more/less columns per Class):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\code\local\CSVReader\Loans.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {                
        var records = new LoanRecord();
        records.Loans = new List<Loan>();  
        int index = 0;

        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            for(int i = 1; index < csv.HeaderRecord.Length; i++)
            {
                var loanItem = new Loan()
                {
                    LoanStart = csv.GetField("LoanStart_DateTime" + i.ToString()),
                    LoanEnd = csv.GetField("LoanEnd_DateTime" + i.ToString())
                };

                records.Loans.Add(loanItem);
                index += 2;
            } 
        }                
    }
}
```

Classes:

```
public class LoanRecord
{
    public List<Loan> Loans { get; set; }
}

public class Loan
{
    public string LoanStart { get; set; }
    public string LoanEnd { get; set; }
}
```

You'll then need to do something with your records but they'll be available as a list of loans:

[image: Loan Records]

Comment: My code is similar to this example: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-properties/

Comment: Can you include an example of your source CSV data? I'm assuming your headers are LoanStart_DateTime and LoanEnd_DateTime or similar? You just have to map against those properties for each as per https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/enumerate-class-records/

Comment: In fact, looking at your updated code, `var records = csv.GetRecords<LoanRecord>();` is returning an IEnumerable of `LoanRecord` already. You just need to make your LoanRecord class have one instance of each property, LoanStart and LoanEnd, like in the 'Loan' class in my example. I'll edit my answer to match.

Comment: I updated the csv format in the question, yes you're right about headers, how can I do the mapping part for the loan class example you posted

Comment: Ah, okay. Your CSV is badly designed from a normalisation view-point. I'd expect a series of rows of data for each loan rather than an indeterminate series of incrementing headers. Where is your source coming from (do you have control of it)? You have to explicitly map each header item which is more difficult this way.